# Using SQLite and Inner Joins to Find Unique Pairs and Number of Pair Matches

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count, inner-join

If we have the following two tables, "teachers" and "classes", how do we use an INNER JOIN statement to produce the final table where

1. "teacher1_id" and "teacher2_id" represent all the unique combinations of teachers who have taught the same class at least 2 times
2. "pair_count" represents the number of same classes "teacher1_id" and "teacher2_id" have taught and
3. "average_teacher_rating" represents the average rating of those same classes taught by "teacher1_id" and "teacher2_id"?

"teachers" table

```
teachers

class_id    teacher_id    teacher_name    class_count
1111        1234          Smith           2
1111        2345          Jones           4
2222        1234          Smith           2
2222        2345          Jones           4
1111        5678          Taylor          2
3333        2345          Jones           4
4444        5678          Taylor          2
4444        2345          Jones           4
```

"classes" table

```
classes

id        class_name      rating
1111      Math            60
2222      Biology         70
3333      Psychology      50
4444      Physics         80
5555      Chemistry       30
6666      Economics       60
7777      Computing       70
8888      Statistics      90
```

And we want the final table to look like:

```
teacher1_id      teacher2_id     pair_count   average_teacher_rating
1234             2345            2            65           
2345             5678            2            70
```

I tried the following code in sqlite but it did not give the desired result (as found in the final table above).

```
SELECT 
    t.teacher1_id
    , t.teacher2_id
    , COUNT(t.teacher1_id = t.teacher2_id)
    , (c.rating1 + c.rating2) / COUNT(t.teacher1_id = t.teacher2_id)
FROM teachers t
INNER JOIN classes c on c.id = t.class_id
WHERE COUNT(t.teacher1_id = t.teacher2_id) > 1;
```

Comment: How do you define what is `teacher1` and what is `teacher2` and how do you know how to pair them? Why does your output only contain 2 rows, all rows in your input has a `class_count` >= 2 and except for `class_id` = 3333 all have multiple teachers per class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following may be along the lines of what you want :-

```
WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.teacher_id AS teacher1_id, 
            t1.teacher_name AS t1name,
            t2.teacher_id AS teacher2_id, 
            t2.teacher_name AS t2name, 
            c.class_name,
            avg(c.rating) AS average_teacher_rating,
            count(c.class_name) AS pair_count
        FROM teachers AS t1
        LEFT JOIN classes AS c ON t1.class_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN teachers AS t2 ON t1.class_id = t2.class_id AND t1.teacher_id < t2.teacher_id
        GROUP BY teacher1_id,teacher2_id
        HAVING pair_count > 1
    )
SELECT teacher1_id, teacher2_id, pair_count, average_teacher_rating FROM cte1
;
```

This results in :-

[image]

- The above could be simplified as the subquery isn't required. However, the additional values may prove to be useful.

i.e. It could be :-

```
SELECT 
    t1.teacher_id AS teacher1_id, 
    t2.teacher_id AS teacher2_id, 
    avg(c.rating) AS average_teacher_rating,
    count(c.class_name) AS pair_count
FROM teachers AS t1
JOIN teachers AS t2 ON t1.class_id = t2.class_id AND t1.teacher_id < t2.teacher_id
JOIN classes AS c ON t1.class_id = c.id
GROUP BY teacher1_id,teacher2_id
HAVING pair_count > 1
;
```

Comment: Good supplement as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select 
    t1.teacher_id as t1
    , t2.teacher_id as t2
    , count()
    , avg(c.rating)
from teachers t1 inner join teachers as t2
on t1.class_id = t2.class_id and t1.teacher_id < t2.teacher_id
left join classes c on c.id = t1.class_id
group by t1, t2
having count()>1;
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/08940/1).